# What are the ways I can write this differently? - static bool M (int x) => x%2 == 0;

Tags: c#, function, action, predicate

I'm currently studying for a test and I've looked up what Function, Action and Predicate mean and I know that only Action doesn't have a return value and Predicate returns a bool value which is what I need in my question. This is the code I got in the question:

```
static bool M (int x) => x%2 == 0;
```

These are the potential answers given:

```
A) Func <bool, int> A = M;

B) Func <int, bool> B = M;

C) Action <int, bool> C = M;

D) Predicate <int> D = M;
```

Based on what I've learned and some simple logic it should be B and D, right? Can someone confirm this for me?

Comment: It would be B since a value is returned with Func.   Action does not return a value, therefore C thinks that there will be 2 inputs, an int and a bool.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question with results of you running that code? It is unclear what type of confirmation (outside trying it yourself) you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's a theoretical test I'm trying to study for and I'm not sure how to check this while running it, so I'm trying to learn theoretically like they're telling us to do. I knwo the question isn't the best.

Comment: @RickDavin Is there a reason why it wouldn't be D?

Comment: If you put the code into a compiler it will tell you which ones are and are not valid.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ask the compiler:

[image: compiled code]

Clearly A) & C) are compiler errors. So, B) & C) are correct.

The `Func<int, bool>` delegate for B) looks like this:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

And the `Predicate<int>` delegate for D) looks like this:

```
public delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj);
```

Both match the signature for `M`.

Comment: No space after `//`? 

Comment: @tymtam - What's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing really, but as with `Func <bool, int> x` and `Func<bool, int> x` some spacing is just better than others :)

Answer (score -3):

You can call a static function by it's class. For example:

```
public class yourClass
{
> public static void DoSomething(bool isTrue)
> {
> //Here you can do some things
> }
}
yourClass.DoSomething(true);
```

if you want a function to return some value eg bool, string etc

```
Public class yourClass
{
>public static bool DoSomething(bool isTrue)
>{
>>if(isTrue)
>>{
>>return false;
>>}
>>else
>>{
>>return true;
>>}
>}
}
bool isItTrue = yourClass.DoSomething(true);
```

A function that returns a value must always have a return value. If you remove the else-part from the example above, you will get an error that not all code returns a value.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: The question title was misleading, I'll give you that.

Comment: @Enigmativity youré right. It's getting to late here. My apologies!